# How do I override style in MUI across the app

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Im trying to apply background color in reactJS using MUI 5 to all the buttons inside my application. I created a theme and changed the primary color inside the palette to this

```
export const theme = createTheme({
palette: {
    primary: {
        main: '#3394D1',
        dark: '#2978B5'
    },
    secondary: {
        main: '#1976d2'
    },
    error: {
        main: '#f44336',
        dark: '#d32f2f'
    },
    success: {
        main: '#4caf50',
        dark: '#388e3c'
    }
```

for some reason the color is not applied, when I print to the console the theme I can see the colors are fine so it's not problem with the theme definition. the color that applied is the default if i put style to the button and put the background color to the palette.primary.main its working but i dont want to go all over the button and add this line

I tried to override also the button like this and still not working

```
components: {
    MuiButton: {
        styleOverrides: {
            root: {
                backgroundColor: '#3394D1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i tried all the combination above

Comment: you need to have  variant="contained" applied, and of course color="primary"

Comment: i have it both, still not working